# Как объяснить тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, инфинитив

Почему автор ставит тире?

> "Он осознает свое предназначение – спасать жизни".

Я бы понял, если бы оно выглядело так: "Его предназначение – спасать жизни" (тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в простом предложении).
Однако предложение, написанное выше, не является простым. Там есть две основы, и поэтому такое правило не работает, тогда на каком основании стоит тире?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Неопределенная форма глагола может быть любым членом предложения. В данном случае это определение, а само предложение – простое (с одной основой):

***Он осознает свое предназначение*** (какое?) ***– спасать жизни.***

> 3. Несогласованное определение, выраженное неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом), перед которой можно поставить слова *а именно,* отделяется посредством **тире:** *…Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с единственным желанием — **сделать добро!*** (Ч.); *Но прекрасен данный жребий — **просиять и умереть*** (Бр.); *…Мы все одержимы одной страстью — **сопротивляться*** (Кетл.); *С батареи получен приказ — **не отнимать трубку от уха и каждые пять минут проверять линию*** (Кат.); *Своей беззащитностью она вызывала в нём рыцарские чувства — **заслонить, оградить, защитить;*** *Откуда вы право взяли себе такое — **судить?***
>    Подобные определения носят пояснительный характер.

Источник: [*Несогласованные определения*](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110) (справочник Розенталя).